# Problem autowiring in implementation of AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: spring, autowired, uncaughtexceptionhandler, spring-async

I have a configuration class as such:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringAsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private AppConfigProperties appConfigProperties;

    @Autowired
    private AsyncExceptionHandler asyncExceptionHandler;

    @Bean("asyncExecutor")
    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(appConfigProperties.getThreadpoolCorePoolSize());
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(appConfigProperties.getThreadpoolMaxPoolSize());
        executor.setQueueCapacity(appConfigProperties.getThreadpoolQueueCapacity());
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("threadPoolExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return asyncExceptionHandler;
    }
}
```

And the ExceptionHandler here:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class AsyncExceptionHandler implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler {

    @Autowired
    private SynchronizationHelper synchronizationHelper;

    @Override
    public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable throwable, Method method, Object... obj) {

        log.error("*** ASYNC Exception message - " + throwable);

        if("synchronize".equals(method.getName())) {
            synchronizationHelper.(...)
            (...)
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that on uncaught exception (in method annotated with `@Async`), it does not go through the method `handleUncaughtException`, even though `getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler()` returns the right bean.

Any idea?

**UPDATE**

I figured out that removing the autowiring in my class AsyncExceptionHandler (*which is not what I want*), it then enters into the method `handleUncaughtException` on uncaught exception.

Why is that?

Comment: @M. Deinum Have you just read the **entire** question before marking as duplicate and pointing to a different question? I am not asking about why it is null...

Comment: Yes I did. And it is null because it isn't a bean... So to fix make it a bean which is exactly the same as the question marked as duplicate.

Comment: Which is what I have... I put the example with null at the end to say it goes through at that time, but not when I have a proper bean...

Comment: No it isn't... When it is `null` the `AsyncExceptionHandler` isn't a bean, but just an inlined instance creation of it. It isn't seen by spring and hence doesn't receive anything injected. Create an `@Bean` method to construct the instance and call that from the `getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler` method.

Comment: I updated the question by just "removing the last paragraph" which seems to cause a misunderstanding. The code as I mentioned since the beginning gets a proper bean via @Component, or else I am missing something?

Comment: @M.Deinum can you "unmark" the question as duplicate? As it is clearly not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arised from

```
@Autowired
private SynchronizationHelper synchronizationHelper;
```

The bean `synchronizationHelper` was autowired with many beans etc., which *somehow* (I do not clearly understand how exactly) disabled the behavior of `asyncExceptionHandler`.

I created a simple `@Service` bean which only does what I need in my method `handleUncaughtException` (which is updating the state of my task in DB), which I autowired the same way, and now everything works fine...

I do not time for extra investigations here, if somebody has any idea it would be welcome.